# Cannot detect if User is Logged in when using Paginator (backbone.js)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, backbone.js, laravel

I am using the [Backbone.js Paginator](http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/) plugin. It does infinite scroll pagination well by defining its own Collection for the models involved in the pagination. If the user is logged in, the PHP backend will return the Backbone object with an additional attribute `is_liked` to cause that item to have a different CSS styling.

**Problem**: When the Paginator plugin (with its own Collection `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager`) does a GET `fetch` request on the backend, the backend is not able to determine if the user is logged in! However, when I use the usual `Backbone.Collection`, the backend is able to determine whether the user is logged in! It works with a `$.post()` too. This makes me think the problem lies in the plugin's `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager`

*I am checking the results by using the Network section of Chrome's developer tools. If the authentication check works, `api/test` can be seen to return some data about the user. If login status cannot be determined, it returns null*

**UPDATE:** The `GET` request sent by `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager` collection does not include the `Cookie` info in the headers that is found in the `GET` request sent by `Backbone.Collection`. Could this be the problem? How can I force `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager` to not strip out the cookie data from the headers?

What is happening here? And how can I solve this (without rewriting my own pagination code)?

**Auth Test using PHP Backend (Laravel Framework)**

```
Route::any('api/test', function() {
    // This will return some data of the user if logged in
    return json_encode(Auth::user());  
});
```

**Typical Backbone Collection [Works]**

```
SimilarUserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: 'api/test'
});
```

**Paginator's Collection [Doesnt Work]**

```
PhotoCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({
    model: Photo,

    paginator_core: {
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'api/test'
        },

    paginator_ui: {
        firstPage: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 7,
        totalPages: 10
    },

    server_api: {

        'page': function() { return this.currentPage; }
    },

    parse: function (response) {

        return response;
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you determining login based on a cookie that is sent? On an auth header? How? Your first collection (that works) uses your `user` model, but the section collection (which doesn't) uses your `photo` model

Comment: Both collections does a `fetch()` on the same URL which checks whether the user is logged in, so I guess the `Model` will not matter, but I may be wrong. The PHP framework uses a database session, so I guess that means storing a cookie with its session data stored in the database. I use the PHP framework's builtin function to get if the user is logged in.

Comment: Tried changing the `Model` for `PhotoCollection` from `Photo` to `User`, and it gives the same result.

Comment: Look at the headers you're sending when you call it on `User` and the headers you send when you call it on `Photo`. You're positive the two URLs are identical each time?

Comment: The 2 URLS are identical except for the `GET` variables ie. `http://www.mysite.com/api/test?page=1` and `http://mysite.com/api/test`. I updated the question, it seems that the `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager` is not sending the cookie info in its request headers, but `Backbone.Collection` is! The backend determines whether a user is logged in by looking at the cookies then checking its `sessions` database table.

Comment: OK I guess you found the problem! The paginator collection used `www.mysite.com/api/test` while the rest of the collections used `/api/test` which corresponds to `mysite.com/api/test` since the browser is pointing to `mysite.com` instead of `www.mysite.com`. Now the cookie is sent!

Comment: Does this mean I need to always state the full url for `url` like `www.mysite.com/api/test` instead of using `api/test`, since whether the user access the site through `www.site.com` or `site.com` will affect whether the cookie is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a crossdomain issue:

One Request is to this URL:
http://www.mysite.com/api/test?page=1

And the other to this:
http://mysite.com/api/test

For the browsers www.mysite.com is totally different so if the Cookie is generated on www.mysite.com requests to mysite.com will not contain it. Be sure that both requests goes to the same domain and you will not have the Cookie issue.